# Is this React prop passing pattern bad for memory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been seeing this pattern for passing props to a component:

`<Component { ...{ propToPass, anotherProp } } />`

as opposed to:

`<Component propToPass={propToPass} anotherProp={anotherProp} />`

I was wondering if instantiating an object and immediately spreading the contents could potentially hog memory or if the difference is negligible?

Comment: Well, if you have thousands of keys in props it will affect memory, else, you shouldn't notice it.

Comment: And even then, the only way to know is to measure!

Comment: I believe its transpiled the same way

Comment: Reminds me: "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/) (or at least most of it) in programming.”

Comment: Kind of related since immutability implies the creation of a lot of objects: [Does immutability hurt performance in JavaScript?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/304574/183033)

Comment: There exist a [rule on eslint](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md) to prevent props spreading (the `{...this.props}` notation), which explains that it's just a question of readability, no note of performance though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

React JSX is usually transformed with Babel, and you can use the Babel playground online to see what it compiles to.

```js
// input
const e1 = <Component { ...{ propToPass, anotherProp } } />

const e2 = <Component propToPass={propToPass} anotherProp={anotherProp} />
```

```js
// output
"use strict";

var e1 = /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Component, {
  propToPass: propToPass,
  anotherProp: anotherProp
});
var e2 = /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(Component, {
  propToPass: propToPass,
  anotherProp: anotherProp
});
```

They're the same! So you won't see any difference.